# Ejecute una restauración de paquetes de NuGet para generar el archivo

Tags: visual-studio, .net, nuget

como puedo reinstalar o eliminar y volver a instalar mis paquetes nuget ya que me pide un usuario y contraseña para poder realizar este proceso en mi proyecto e intentado reinstalar por consola y a través del administrador de paquetes pero no me ni permite ni actualizar ni desinstalar y me dice

> Error NETSDK1004  No se encuentra el archivo de recursos
> 'C:\Proyecto\obj\project.assets.json'. Ejecute una restauración de
> paquetes de NuGet para generar el archivo.    C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 198

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]